# Button click to auto call on android 6 not working

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({     action: Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,     data: 'tel:1234567' }); Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

and in tiapp.xml I have permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Auto call on button click is not working on Android 6. How to ask permission on android 6? The permission.js does not have any code for CALL_PHONE permission

Answer (score 0):

var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({ action: Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,     data: 'tel:1234567' }); Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);

and in tiapp.xml I have permission

Auto call on button click is not working on Android 6. How to ask permission on android 6? The permission.js does not have any code for CALL_PHONE permission

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Titanium.Platform.openUrl('tel:'1234567);
```

It will open the dialler with pre-populated number, but it will not work on simulator.

for more look in the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Platform-method-openURL) and [code](http://assets.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/app_u/tce_labs/Finished/URLSchemes.zip), also [link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/td/09+-+App+Interconnections)

Comment: I do not want to open the dialler, I am looking for auto call. Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL is not working on Android 6 it is throwing permission denied exception, same working for earlier Android versions